# How to perform an inner join on 2 files

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I got 2 files, one of them has questions, and the other has (multiple) answers for each question.

For example:

**Questions:**

```
Q1,What is the name of your son?
Q2,How are you today?
```

**Answers:**

```
A1,Q1,George
A2,Q1,David
A1,Q2,Good
A2,Q2,Nice
A3,Q2,Amazing
```

**What I'm trying to get as an output is:**

```
Q1,What is the name of your son? A1,George
Q1,What is the name of your son? A2,David
Q2,How are you today? A1,Good
Q2,How are you today? A2,Nice
Q2,How are you today? A3,Amazing
```

I've been searching for a solution but I couldn't find something straightforward.

I tried mapping into QID as key, and question/AID,answer as value (e.g. Q1 How are you today? || Q1 A1,Good), and then when reducing, finding the question (the only one without an "Ax," at the beginning) and adding it to each answer, but the idea doesn't seem right (and doesn't work, but that's another thing)

I hope someone can help me out with this. Thanks!

Comment: Because unfortunately I'm required to do so.. I agree it isn't ideal here.

Comment: Are you using Hive, Pig, or Spark? Why does it need to be mapreduce?

Comment: I'm using Hadoop. Because I'm required to do so.

Comment: Hadoop is HDFS and YARN. You don't write code "using Hadoop". Each of the tools I mentioned are part of the Hadoop ecosystem. Even the below answer uses Spark

Answer (score 0):

I would identify the Keys as Q_Id in both do a mapside join ?  (This is under the circumstances that one of the two files fit in memory)  This would be more efficent than doing a map-reudce.

[(mapside join example)](https://gist.github.com/airawat/6587341)?

If neither files fits in memory map > reduce on (Q_id)

Here's an example of what it would look like in spark:

```
val questions = Seq(
        ("Q1","What is the name of your son?"),
        ("Q2","How are you today?"))
    .toDF("Q_id","text")
val answers = Seq(
        ("A1","Q1","George"),
        ("A2","Q1","David"),
        ("A1","Q2","Good"),      
        ("A2","Q2","Nice"),        
        ("A3","Q2","Amazing"))
    .toDF("A_id","Q_id","answer_text")
questions
    .join(answers, questions("Q_id") === answers("Q_id"))
    .select(
        questions("Q_id"),
        questions("text"),
        answers("A_id"),
        answers("answer_text")) 
    .show()

+----+--------------------+----+-----------+
|Q_id|                text|A_id|answer_text|
+----+--------------------+----+-----------+
|  Q1|What is the name ...|  A1|     George|
|  Q1|What is the name ...|  A2|      David|
|  Q2|  How are you today?|  A1|       Good|
|  Q2|  How are you today?|  A2|       Nice|
|  Q2|  How are you today?|  A3|    Amazing|
+----+--------------------+----+-----------+
```